# How do you add item to ActionBarSherlock after onCreate?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Okay, when my app starts it has two tabs, and one action in the action bar, when I switch to the second tab, i change the layout, and I want to remove the action I have in the bar, and add a different one, any easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working!

All you have to do is add conditional statements to your onCreateOptionsMenu, and then simply invalidate the menu when you switch the tab! Hope this helps someone!

Conditional:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            if (getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex() == 1) {
                menu.add("Share")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_share)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
            }
            if (getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex() == 0)) {
                menu.add("Settings")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_manage)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);      
            }

            return true;
        }
```

And to invalidate:

```
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Answer (score 2):

I presume your tabs are `Fragments` within a `FragmentActivity`. In that case, you should `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in tab fragments' `onCreate()` methods. And override `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` of the fragments.

The rest will be done for you (like invalidating actionItems after switching tabs etc.)